# Unable to run IntelliJ IDEA CE 12 with Ubuntu Oracle Java 8

Tags: java, linux, oracle, ubuntu, intellij-idea

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 and Oracle Java 8.

I have set the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables.

Here is the terminal output of trying to run IntelliJ:

```
darren@ubuntu:~$ /opt/intellij-idea-ce/bin/idea.sh
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b42, mixed mode)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
Failed to clear URL cache
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(I)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getIcon(IconLoader.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.readExternal(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.getShadowInstance(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:426)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.getAppIconImages(AppUIUtil.java:66)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateWindowIcon(AppUIUtil.java:49)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:46)
    ... 6 more
ERROR: Error while accessing com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start with arguments: []
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:190)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(I)Ljava/lang/Class;
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.IconLoader.getIcon(IconLoader.java:116)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.readExternal(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:491)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationInfoImpl.getShadowInstance(ApplicationInfoImpl.java:426)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.getAppIconImages(AppUIUtil.java:66)
    at com.intellij.ui.AppUIUtil.updateWindowIcon(AppUIUtil.java:49)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:46)
    ... 6 more
ERROR: Error while accessing com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start with arguments: []
java.lang.AssertionError: Error while accessing com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start with arguments: []
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.DefaultLogger.error(DefaultLogger.java:55)
    at com.intellij.openapi.diagnostic.Logger.error(Logger.java:65)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$2.run(PluginManager.java:194)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

Exception: java.lang.AssertionError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "Idea Main Thread 12.1#IC-129.161, eap:false"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a [known issue](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-106251), JDK 8 has removed a method that IDEA is using. It was fixed in [IDEA 12.1.5](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12.1+EAP).

We recommend using supported and released JDK versions to avoid problems, like JDK 1.7.

Comment: Someone needs to tell Jetbrains this as well, since they recommend 8 in this tutorial http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Installing_and_running_PHPStorm_on_Ubuntu

Comment: @Shane This issue doesn't apply to the current IDE versions, it was fixed more than a year ago.

Answer (score 8):

You may already have one instance of IDEA running. Go ahead and check:

```
$ ps -ef | grep idea
```

Use `kill` or `kill -9` to stop that instance then try restarting it.

Comment: How did you conclude that that might be the reason?

Comment: Four years ago? Beats me.

Comment: I am curios because I have never seen a NoSuchMethod error being fixed by restarting the program.

Comment: You have now! :D