# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize

Tags: java, maven

When building a Java 8 project with Maven:

```
mvn clean package
```

I get this message:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=128m; support was removed in 8.0

How to remove this message?

Comment: See http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964458 for a full description

Comment: You may already have one instance of IDEA running.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20553943/3741698

Answer (score 175, accepted):

[Compatibility Guide for JDK 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html) says that in Java 8 the command line flag `MaxPermSize` has been removed. The reason is that the permanent generation was removed from the hotspot heap and was moved to native memory.
So in order to remove this message
edit **MAVEN_OPTS** Environment User Variable:

**Java 7**

```
MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

**Java 8**

```
MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx512m
```

Comment: And the reason is that the whole PermGen space has been removed in Oracle's JRE 8, AFAIK.

Comment: If someone does not know how to do this - `sudo gedit ~/.profile`, add the line from the answer there and save the file.

Comment: I have this option set in ~/.bashrc file

Comment: @gotqn Why would you `sudo` edit a file in your home folder? Seems like very strange practice to me.

Answer (score 22):

The **JDK 8 HotSpot JVM** is now using native memory for the representation of class metadata and is called **Metaspace**.

The permanent generation has been removed. The `PermSize` and  `MaxPermSize` are ignored and a warning is issued if they are present on the command line.

Comment: This only indirectly answers the question... The answer is "remove the flags to remove the warning". As the [insightful comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize#comment54226301_32365351) by @ohad-schneider reveals, there is no _one_ single replacement for them.

Answer (score 13):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=size
```

Sets the maximum permanent generation space size (in bytes). This option was deprecated in JDK 8, and superseded by the `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize` option.

```
-XX:PermSize=size
```

Sets the space (in bytes) allocated to the permanent generation that triggers a garbage collection if it is exceeded. This option was deprecated in **JDK 8**, and superseded by the `-XX:MetaspaceSize` option.

Comment: I think this was downvoted because it implies that you should switch previous uses of `MaxPermGen` with `MaxMetaSpaceSize` which is misleading, since their roles have practically reversed. Before Java 8 class metadata space resided in PermGen which was limited by 32/64MB, and `MaxPerGen` was used to *increase* it. Starting from Java 8 however, PermGen is no more and class metadata space is unlimited, so `MaxMetaspace` size is actually used to *decrease* it. For more information see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31463972/67824

Answer (score 8):

In JBoss EAP 6.4, right click on the server and open launch configuration under VM argument you will find

```
{-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: jboss-eap" -server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m}
```

update it to

```
{-Dprogram.name=JBossTools: JBoss 6.4" -server -Xms512m -Xmx512m}
```

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got similar message when running command line mvn (version 3.3.3) on Linux with Java 8.
By opening maven script /$MAVEN-HOME/bin/mvn, found the following line

```
MAVEN_OPTS="$(concat_lines "$MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/.mvn/jvm.config") $MAVEN_OPTS"
```

Where $MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR by default is your home directory.
So two places you can take a look, first is file $MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/.mvn/jvm.config if it exists. Secondly look at files possibly set up the environment variable MAVEN_OPTS. Candidate files are .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile and those files included by them such as /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc

I located

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m"
```

in .bashrc in my system, change it to

```
export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m"
```

issue resolved

Comment: adding this in .zshrc file resolved this issue:  export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xmx512m"

Answer (score 1):

in case some one still get this kind of message. Its happen because you add JVM argument when running maven project. Because it is related with maven you can check your `pom.xml` file on your project.

find this line `<argLine>...</argLine>`, on my project I also have argument below

```
<argLine>-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argLine>
```

you should replace `MaxPermSize` argument as `-Xms123m -Xmx123m`, since `MaxPermSize` is already deprecated and wont take any effect on your JVM config :

```
<argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx512m  -XX:+TieredCompilation -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1</argLine>
```

Answer (score -1):

Please to solve this problem we just have set installed JDK path in

> standalone.conf

file which under the ***bin*** folder of JBoss\Wildfly Server. To solve this we do the following steps:

1. Open the ***standlone.conf*** file which under JBoss_or_wildfly\bin folder
2. Within this file find for ***#JAVA_HOME*** text.
3. Remove the **#** character and set your installed JDK path as 
   ***JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65"***
   Hope this will solve your problem
   Thanks

Comment: The original problem is in a maven project. It has nothing to do with JBoss.

Answer (score -5):

For Eclipse users...

Click Run —> Run configuration —> are —> set Alternate JRE for 1.6 or 1.7