# Server Spring suit tool : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

Tags: spring

When I start the server of Spring Suite tool (Pivotal tc Server) I get this message :

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0

I have download other IDE Spring Suite tool that contain other server and I created other workSpace but always I get the some Error.

Comment: This is not an error, it is a warning from the virtual machine. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize) for details on what the warning means.

Comment: i dont think that is a warning beacause i can not run any project !!!!!! .... I found this responce : MAVEN_OPTS -Xmx512m .. but i dont know where i tape this commande ?

Comment: If you can't run any projects, then the cause is something else.

Answer (score 0):

The command line flags **PermSize** and **MaxPermSize** have been removed in JDK 8 and are ignored. If used on the command line a warning will be emitted for each.

Full description why it changed you can find here:
[JDK-6964458 : Reimplement class meta-data storage to use native memory](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6964458)