# Eclipse reporting error while run wildfly server

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, java, eclipse-mars

Running Wildfly server in Eclipse is reporting an error below in red:

`OpenJDK Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0`

Eclipse is running under Ubuntu. I'm not that familiar with Java, but I guess there is a problem with Java configuration. Because executing any Java code in eclipse was giving the same error, although application was working. Tomcat was perfectly running but WildFly is causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 the command line flag MaxPermSize has been removed.
Check
[Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize)