# Puppetserver service fails to start

Tags: java, vagrant, puppet

I have a Vagrant CentOS VM running with `ps.memory = 2048` RAM allocated.

When I try to start the `puppetserver` service:

```
$ puppet --version
4.4.0
$ sudo puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
Error: Could not start Service[puppetserver]: Execution of '/bin/systemctl start puppetserver' returned 1: Job for puppetserver.service failed. See 'systemctl status puppetserver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
Error: /Service[puppetserver]/ensure: change from stopped to running failed: Could not start Service[puppetserver]: Execution of '/bin/systemctl start puppetserver' returned 1: Job for puppetserver.service failed. See 'systemctl status puppetserver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
service { 'puppetserver':
  ensure => 'stopped',
}
$ journalctl -xn
No journal files were found.
$ systemctl status puppetserver.service
puppetserver.service - puppetserver Service
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service; disabled)
  Process: 4708 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install --directory --owner=puppet --group=puppet --mode=775 /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4709 (java);         : 4710 (bash)
   CGroup: /system.slice/puppetserver.service
           ├─4709 /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p -Djava.security.egd=/...
           └─control
             ├─4710 /bin/bash /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/ezbake-functions.sh wait_for_app
             └─4755 sleep 1
```

My `JAVA_ARGS` from `/etc/sysconfig/puppetserver`:

```
JAVA_ARGS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g"
```

As requested, the `puppetserver.service` file:

```
$ cat /usr/lib/systemd/system/puppetserver.service
[Unit]
Description=puppetserver Service
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/puppetserver
User=puppet
TimeoutStartSec=120
TimeoutStopSec=60
Restart=on-failure
StartLimitBurst=5

PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install --directory --owner=puppet --group=puppet --mode=775 /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver

ExecStart=/usr/bin/java $JAVA_ARGS \
          '-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %%p' \
          -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom \
          -cp "${INSTALL_DIR}/puppet-server-release.jar" clojure.main \
          -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main \
          --config "${CONFIG}" \
          -b "${BOOTSTRAP_CONFIG}" $@

KillMode=process

ExecStartPost=/bin/bash "${INSTALL_DIR}/ezbake-functions.sh" wait_for_app

SuccessExitStatus=143

StandardOutput=syslog

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

An attempt at running the `ExecStartPost` command by hand:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %%p' -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg

RuntimeError: Got 2 failure(s) while initializing: File[/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver]: change from 0700 to 0750 failed: failed to set mode 0700 on /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver: Operation not permitted - No message available; File[/var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver]: change from 0775 to 0755 failed: failed to set mode 0775 on /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver: Operation not permitted - No message available
```

So I tried again, but this time I changed some directory permissions, but still similar error (which doesn't make sense given I just changed the mode?):

```
$ sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /var/run/puppetlabs/
$ sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /var/log/puppetlabs/
$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/run/puppetlabs/

$ /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %%p' -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1g; support was removed in 8.0
RuntimeError: Got 1 failure(s) while initializing: File[/var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver]: change from 0775 to 0755 failed: failed to set mode 0775 on /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver: Operation not permitted - No message available
                use at /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/settings.rb:1007
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Please provide the puppetserver.service file

Comment: @fge: added to the question

Comment: _"See 'systemctl status puppetserver.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details."_ -- what do these say?

Comment: I have shown the results of both of those commands in the question...

Comment: @JimGarrison the output of those two commands are right below

Comment: What happens if you try and run this command line by hand?

Comment: Which command by hand?

Comment: The full command to start the puppet server (that of `ExecStart`)

Comment: @fge: done, and included output in question. Great lead - some permissions issues, but not sure why. Running that command with sudo yields no errors (and simply hangs forever), but `sudo puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running` fails in another SSH session, so it doesn't look like that is success either.

Comment: Can you try and run a simple jar with your Java invocation and the JVM args instead of the puppet server jar? Does that make a difference? Ie, try to run `/usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %%p' -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -jar someVeryBasic.jar`

Comment: Hm, I don't have any jars - any simple one I can download somewhere?

Comment: why do you say this is an `OnOutOfMemoryError` ? Doesn't look like it from your post.

Comment: I thought it was but it appears it may not be, you are correct

Answer (score 2):

Are you certain that it’s an OnOutOfMemory error?  I ask because I found that the latest PuppetServer includes a newer version of logback, as shown by this message in /var/log/messages:

```
Mar 18 01:56:21 puppetserver java: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: ch.qos.logback.core.net.SyslogAppenderBase.createOutputStream()Lch/qos/logback/core/net/SyslogOutputStream;
Mar 18 01:56:21 puppetserver java: at ch.qos.logback.core.net.SyslogAppenderBase.start(SyslogAppenderBase.java:62)
Mar 18 01:56:21 puppetserver java: at ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SyslogAppender.start(SyslogAppender.java:48)
```

If you see, this replace “classic.net.Syslog” in logback.xml with "core.net.Syslog"

```
sed -i_old -e 's/classic.net.Syslog/core.net.Syslog/' /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/logback.xml
```

If that's not the problem, please post your logfiles.

Comment: Ah, yes I think you may be right. The problem could be that the `ExecStartPre` command is chowning the `/var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver` to be user=puppet, group=puppet. I see that when I 1) chown to `vagrant:vagrant`, 2) try to start, 3) it continues to fail, 4) `/var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver` is now owned by `puppet:puppet` (which would fit with perms errors above). The error still looks the same as when I posted in the question above however.

Comment: I should add that commenting out the `ExecStartPre` line in env file doesn't seem to fix either.

Comment: And running the `ExecStart` command with `sudo` still yields error: `RuntimeError: Got 2 failure(s) while initializing: File[/var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver]: change from 0700 to 0750 failed: failed to set mode 0700 on /var/log/puppetlabs/puppetserver: Operation not permitted - No message available; File[/var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver]: change from 0775 to 0755 failed: failed to set mode 0775 on /var/run/puppetlabs/puppetserver: Operation not permitted - No message available`.

Answer (score 2):

You have provided log as

> OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1g;
>   support was removed in 8.0

**So, it is clear that you are using jdk 8 which removed permgen space.**

The Permanent Generation (PermGen) space has completely been removed and is kind of replaced by a new space called `Metaspace`. The consequences of the PermGen removal is that obviously the PermSize and MaxPermSize JVM arguments are ignored and you will never get a `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen error`.

1. So please remove the `-XX:MaxPermSize=1g` portion from `JAVA_ARGS` of location `/etc/sysconfig/puppetserver`

> JAVA_ARGS="-Xms1g -Xmx1g"

So

2. And then,

your command will be look like below:

```
$ /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %%p' -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg
```

or

```
$ /usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg
```

Please try this 2 commands. I hope both will run successfully. For caution purpose, I have added both.

N.B: There is no need to change the file permission. keep them as before you using.

**Otherwise, if you don't want to change anything, you can downgrade `java 8` to `java 7`**

Related Link:

1. [PermGen elimination in JDK 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339707/permgen-elimination-in-jdk-8)
2. [Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize)
3. [JAVA 8 XX:PERMSIZE AND XX:MAXPERMSIZE DISAPPEARING](https://archenroot.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/java-8-xxpermsize-and-xxmaxpermsize-disappearing/)
4. [JDK 8 Milestones](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8/milestones)
5. [JEP 122: Remove the Permanent Generation](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/122)

Answer (score 1):

@lollercoster, you're starting your service with:

```
sudo puppet resource service puppetserver ensure=running
```

But your next command is not telling which user it is

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %%p' -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg
```

Please run whoami directly before your run the above command:

```
whoami
/usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill -9 %%p' -Djava.security.egd=/dev/urandom -cp /opt/puppetlabs/server/apps/puppetserver/puppet-server-release.jar clojure.main -m puppetlabs.trapperkeeper.main --config /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/conf.d -b /etc/puppetlabs/puppetserver/bootstrap.cfg
```

Why this commands?
I am pretty confident that your issue is a permission/usercontext issue and following commands make it more worse:

```
$ sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /var/run/puppetlabs/
$ sudo chown -R vagrant:vagrant /var/log/puppetlabs/
$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/run/puppetlabs/
```

with the above cases you have to do a sudo on the right user context to have the files writable, but it depends if the other data is writable. So you can give it a try, but I would use the puppet user created for the service

```
User=puppet
```

So your puppet service runs as user puppet, but your logfiles are under vagrant user control, and not writable for puppet user.

So I would also try to switch back to:

```
$ sudo chown -R puppet /var/run/puppetlabs/
$ sudo chown -R puppet /var/log/puppetlabs/
$ sudo chmod -R 0755 /var/run/puppetlabs/
```

**Java**

Also I suggest you NOT to mess around with the JVM heap parameters, except you know what you do. Since you do not need to enforce a lower and a max bound on Java VM heap since JDK5. I would only limit to the upper bound

```
-Xmx1g
```

The heap and the real allocated mem will be managed well by the javaVM. As JVM needs more it will step by step increase the heap and keep the needed size (no downsizing to a lower value will occur). So you will have a better used RAM on your machine.

Also please switch to the Oracle JVM. I am facing often issues with security and Compatibility with OpenJDK. So my first test is to run it on the latest needed JDK of Oracle. In your case Oracle JDK8.
But please try first the permission things I mentioned before.

Good luck, and please keep me updated.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this behaviour before. **Do not try to run the commands manually as root, because you will mess up the permissions.** Instead read the logs carefully with `journalctl -xe` and try to understand why the service is failing. In my case I could not start the `puppetserver` service because there was already a private key, but not yet a public certificate.

```
ls /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/`hostname -f`.pem
ls /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/`hostname -f`.pem
```

If one of them is present without the other one, the service will fail to start up. You will see something like this in the log file:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot initialize master with partial state; need all files or none.
```

If you are trying to install `puppetserver` for the first time, so there is no way to break an existing deployment, then you can probably just remove the exisiting private key and `puppetserver` will automatically generate a new pair.

```
rm /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/certs/`hostname -f`.pem
rm /etc/puppetlabs/puppet/ssl/private_keys/`hostname -f`.pem
```

And finally try again to start the `puppetserver` service.

```
service puppetserver start
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/usr/bin/java -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:MaxPermSize=1g
```

Xms and Xms are less than MaxPermSize. this worked for me.