# eclipse maxpermsize=256 issue

Tags: java, eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse but when i click on eclipse installation file it does not run. And when i click on eclipsec file it shows me following message:

```
Javahotspot(TM) 64 bit server VM warning: ignoring option Maxpermsize=256: support was removed in 8.0
```

I have installed latest Java 8.0 on my windows 7. What should i do? I have tried to search but couldn't find any solution on google . Please i am new in programming so provide me reply in easy steps.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bpiDD.png)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize

Comment: infact its a duplicate i have shown my problem but they deleted it because it seems different question to them.

Answer (score 0):

Open eclipse.ini in Eclipse home dir and remove these lines:

```
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
```

Comment: eclipse.ini- which folder in the pic?

Comment: eclipse ... Configuration set... in your picture

Comment: ok i have checked all the folders in configuration folder but no such file there. can you please provide the full path to that file please

Comment: This is eclipse 1kb file in the above window. I have updated 256 to 512MB but same problem. Also there is  a message Java is started but return exit code=13....

Answer (score -1):

I find the solution. I had installed 32Bit eclipse instead 64bit.

Comment: This is not the solution. It helps because you have more recent eclipse version. Just follow the answer of Evgeniy: He says "remove" instad of update to 512. You are able to run a 64 bit eclipse.

Comment: that is the solution because i previously had 32 bit eclipse installed which i have removed and install 64 bit eclipse so problem solved.