# Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning Cannot open file logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory

Tags: java

I'm getting this error when I try to run

```
RACK_ENV=test be rails test test/system/service_provider_map_test.rb —seed 48088

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory
```

**The tests are then timing out with this error**

> Timeout while waiting for cluster status [green] and [1] nodes
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:551:in `sleep': execution expired (Timeout::Error)     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:551:in`block (2 levels) in __wait_for_status'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:542:in `loop'  from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:542:in`block in __wait_for_status'    from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/timeout.rb:108:in
>   `timeout'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:541:in`__wait_for_status'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:364:in `wait_for_green'    from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:280:in`start'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/elasticsearch-extensions-0.0.26/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb:52:in
>   `start'   from
>   /Users/patrickward/Desktop/esh/SDR/test/support/elasticsearch_helpers.rb:38:in`
>   start_elasticsearch'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/Desktop/esh/SDR/test/application_system_test_case.rb:12:in
>   `<class:ApplicationSystemTestCase>'   from
>   /Users/patrickward/Desktop/esh/SDR/test/application_system_test_case.rb:6:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/patrickward/Desktop/esh/SDR/test/system/service_provider_map_test.rb:2:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/Desktop/esh/SDR/test/system/service_provider_map_test.rb:2:in`
>   '    from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in
>   `require'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:14:in`
>   block in require_files'  from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/test_requirer.rb:13:in`
>   require_files'   from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:96:in `plugin_rails_init'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:81:in`
>   block in init_plugins'   from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:79:in
>   `each'    from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:79:in`
>   init_plugins'    from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:130:in
>   `run'     from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/railties-5.1.2/lib/rails/test_unit/minitest_plugin.rb:77:in`run'   from
>   /Users/patrickward/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/minitest-5.11.3/lib/minitest.rb:63:in
>   `block in autorun'

For context: I'm running on a Mac OS, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Duplicated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/

Answer (score 1):

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Cannot open file logs/gc.log due to No such file or directory
```

is not an error it is a warning and misleading. The real error message is

**Timeout while waiting for cluster status [green] and [1] nodes**

elasticsearch-ruby library has a test code which is starting a cluster itself. 
and it comes from this test. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/blob/6.x/elasticsearch-extensions/lib/elasticsearch/extensions/test/cluster.rb Line : 579

```
message = "\nTimeout while waiting for cluster status [#{status}]"
message += " and [#{arguments[:number_of_nodes]}] nodes" if arguments[:number_of_nodes]
    __log message.ansi(:red, :bold)
```

However there was a bug which is pointing your problem. 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-ruby/issues/371
You may need to upgrade your elasticsearch-ruby version to newer one