# How to increase memory/heap in NetBeans 12 (netbeans_default_options)

Tags: java, netbeans, heap-memory

I am attempting to increase the amount of memory allocated to NetBeans 12 by editing the netbeans.conf file (found here: **${nb-install}/etc/netbeans.conf**)

Currently I am adding the following options as such:

> netbeans_default_options -J-Xms4g -J-Xmx12g .....

However I am not confident that this is all that's needed. I am able to find quite a few posts listing these additions, as well as `-J-XX:PermSize=..` and `-J-XX:MaxPermSize=..` but I think maybe PermSize is now ignored? ***All the articles I have been able to find are old posts and for much older version of NetBeans and JDK.***

I'm currently running NetBeans 12.1 and JDK-12.0.1.

Questions:

- Is this all that's needed? Are there more options to add, or other areas I need to address?
- Are there any 'best practices' for how much memory to add based on what is available (I have ~40G of memory on my system)?
- Should I also increase -J-Xxx2m to something bigger?

Comment: Is there a reason that the information here is not sufficient? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19509-01/821-0449/inst_increase_heap_size_t/index.html

Comment: yes, options that have to do with PermSize must have been deprecated and are ignored since Java 8. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22634644/java-hotspottm-64-bit-server-vm-warning-ignoring-option-maxpermsize
setting Xms and Xmx was enough for me