# JBoss 7 startup in standalone mode

Tags: java, reflection, jboss

I am trying to run Jboss in standalone mode after downloading the zip file and extracting it. I run the `standalone.bat` script and get the below error.

```
Calling "D:\Software\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\bin\standalone.conf.bat"
===============================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: D:\Software\JBoss\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final

  JAVA: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.13\bin\java

  JAVA_OPTS: -XX:+TieredCompilation -Dprogram.name=standalone.bat -Xms64M -Xmx512M -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djboss.server.default.config=standalone.xml

===============================================================================

Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:181)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:257)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance(TransformerFactory.java:126)
        at __redirected.__TransformerFactory.<clinit>(__TransformerFactory.java:66)
        at __redirected.__JAXPRedirected.initAll(__JAXPRedirected.java:82)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:85)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module$1.run(Module.java:72)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.<clinit>(Module.java:72)
        at org.jboss.modules.Main.main(Main.java:255)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
l.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.transform.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:169)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider __redirected.__SAXParserFactory could not be instantiated: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:198)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:147)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:226)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:147)
        at java.xml/jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils.getSAXFactory(JdkXmlUtils.java:379)
        at java.xml/jdk.xml.internal.JdkXmlUtils.<clinit>(JdkXmlUtils.java:118)
        at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl.<init>(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:251)
        ... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:187)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:94)
        at __redirected.__RedirectedUtils.loadProvider(__RedirectedUtils.java:87)
        at __redirected.__SAXParserFactory.<init>(__SAXParserFactory.java:102)
        ... 25 more
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32150635/7358869) and removed the `MaxPermSize` option from `standalone.conf.bat` file but it did not resolve my issue, I am using Java 11. Before removing `MaxPermSize` option i was getting error `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Ignoring option MaxPermSize; support was removed in 8.0 support was removed in 8.0`. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss AS 7.1.1 is 10 years old and since then the JDK has evolved quite a lot with modules. You need to specify the proper options for classloading or switch back to an old JDK (like 1.7).

Comment: Where could i find the proper options to be specified?

Comment: You should take a look at wildfly scripts